# ros msg definitions, difference between std_msgs/TYPE and type

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, std-msgs, msg, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

What is the difference in between using

```
std_msgs/Float32 someVariable
```

and

```
float32 someVariable
```

in msg files?

I noticed the latter can be accessed by `my_data.someVariable.data` where the first  needs to be accessed by `my_data.someVariable`

I am sending these messages over rosserial, so what differences are there when using std_msg/Type in a msg file

Best,
C.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328729/ros-msg-definitions,-difference-between-std_msgs/type-and-type/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What is the difference in between using `std_msgs/Float32 someVariable` and `float32 someVariable` in msg files?

The former (`std_msgs/Float32`) is a message, the latter (`float32`) is a type. A message can be published. A bare type cannot.

That is the main difference. The messages in `std_msgs` are essentially bare types *wrapped in a message*, such that they can be published and received.

> I noticed the latter can be accessed by `my_data.someVariable.data` where the first needs to be accessed by `my_data.someVariable`

As the messages in `std_msgs` are wrappers and not the types themselves, any field that is declared to be of type `std_msgs/Float32` essentially embeds a message inside another message. As the base message `std_msgs/Float32` already wraps a plain `float32`, to access the actual data, you first have to go through all the wrappers and finally get to the `data` field that contains the wrapped data type.

For normal usage in custom messages, it doesn't make sense to use the wrapped version of these plain types, as the message you are creating already wraps them in a message (that's the whole point of creating the message).

I would go so far as to say: using any message from `std_msgs` as the type of a field in a custom message is essentially wrong: use the plain type it wraps (so just use `float32` instead of `std_msgs/Float32` for your field).

Finally: even though it's convenient they are there, the messages in `std_msgs` should only be used very sparingly if at all. Publishing a `std_msgs/Float32` carries no semantics whatsoever.

As a publication, it could be the temperature of your coffee. As a subscription, it could be the desired throttle value of your car. Both of these can be encoded with a `float32`. But connecting the two (ie: `coffee_temperature -> engine_throttle`) makes no sense. By using generic messages, there is no way to prevent setting up such connections. If you'd use two different message types with proper semantics, say `ThrottleCommand` and `Temperature`:

1. it becomes impossible to easily connect them (ie: by remapping fi), *and*
2. it's immediately clear that one of the `float32`s actually encodes a temperature and the other the desired throttle value and that these represent entirely different things

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1